# Required String parameter is not present Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, http-request-parameters

I want to access two different pages in my browser using:

```
http://localhost:8080/name?views
```

and

```
http://localhost:8080/name?uviews
```

But I'm getting error Required String parameter 'uviews' is not present when I use first url and I get Required String parameter 'views' is not present when I use second one.

here is my Response body

```
@ResponseBody     
public Object getViewInJson(@RequestParam("views") String views ,@RequestParam("uviews") String uviews) throws IOException{

 loader = new AnalyticsLoader();



    return loader.AnalyticsLoader(views,uviews);
}
```

How can access both views and uviews?

Comment: @RequestParam(value = "views", required = false) or use defaultValue

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Add `required=false` attribute to `@RequestParam`..Change to

```
@RequestParam(required=false,name="views") String view,..
```

Comment: Oh my god.! I do not have words to say thanks. Kept browsing through everywhere for this. Thanks a ton. Wish I could give million up-votes.

Comment: @AjayKumar I feel you bro!

Answer (score 4):

Add `required=false` to the `@RequestParam` notation for both. Or you could decide to explicitly use one, set it to `required=false` and set the other as the `defaultValue`.

See the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html) for further information.

Answer (score 1):

I was using `Postman` for API hit, Adding `required=false` and `defalutValue` might be helpful, but `required=false` results in `NULL Exception`. Then I have `Removed the Headers (can Authorization header)` in Postman and its works.

Answer (score 0):

please check your spring version, there is a bug in 3.2.3.
https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-10592

Answer (score -1):

Instead of:

```
@ResponseBody     
public Object getViewInJson(@RequestParam("views") String views, @RequestParam("uviews") String uviews) throws IOException{
    ...
}
```

Do this:

```
@ResponseBody     
public Object getViewInJson(@RequestParam("views[]") String views, @RequestParam("uviews[]") String uviews) throws IOException{
    ...
}
```

Add brackets to the end of the param, anything else as normal.